# Where does shotwell store its config files?

Tags: 12.10, shotwell

Does anybody have an idea where does Shotwell store its config files?

The problem is:
I made a new installation of 12.10, and decided to use a new hdd for the home directory. I moved all pictures from the old hdd to the new one and copied all files from ~/.gconf/apps/shotwell to the new home folder, but shotwell doesn't see the folder with pictures.

Comment: Related Question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/188081/how-to-reset-shotwell-to-its-original-state

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Shotwell 0.12.3 and earlier ->  `~/.shotwell`

Shotwell **0.13.0 or later** -> `~/.local/share/shotwell`

[Shotwell's FAQ page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell/FAQ) has much more detail and a better explanation of how to migrate to a new hard drive.

Comment: In addition from `0.13`, the photo thumbnails are now in `~/.cache/shotwell`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you won't be able to simply copy over the files in the .gconf directory, while your user is logged in on, as the running instance will take precedence, and changing the files out from under the process will have no effect.

And Shotwell uses dconf to store its settings now, so you'll likely need to export them from the one installation, and then import them in the new installation. I don't know if Shotwell itself has any export/import feature for backing up and restoring settings, but some applications do.

To export/import from/to gconf while it is running, you can use the `gconftool` command line utility with it's --dump and --load options. Unfortunately, it seems the `gsettings` command does not have similar options.